# find dev_0*/src -name t0.c -type f: how exactly find traverses files: sequentially or in parallel?

Tags: find

For this command `find dev_0*/src -name t0.c -type f` how exactly `find` traverses files: sequentially or in parallel?

I see traversing in sequential mode like this:

```
traverse: find dev_00/src/<all files>
traverse: find dev_01/src/<all files>
traverse: <and so on>
traverse: find dev_0N/src/<all files>
```

I see traversing in parallel mode like this:

```
traverse: find dev_00/src/<some file>
traverse: find dev_01/src/<some file>
traverse: find dev_00/src/<some file>
traverse: find dev_01/src/<some file>
traverse: find dev_01/src/<some file>
traverse: <and so on>
traverse: find dev_0N/src/<some file>
```

Reason of the question: after running `find dev_0*/src -name t0.c` can I be sure that `find` traverses files sequentially?

Extra question: in the scenario above is it possible to make `find` traverse files in parallel?

Comment: This has been party answered here https://serverfault.com/questions/181787/find-command-default-sorting-order/181815

Comment: All `find` implementations that I know of are sequential